# Syncing two videos with different framerates using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, framerate

It should be easy. Actually, it probably is easy. I'm probably just dumb. I have two videos, shot at the same time but with two different cameras. One video is 1920x1080@60, the other is 640x480@29.85.  I want to make one video where they both run concurrently (picture-in-picture, split screen, whatever; that's not the problem). When I do this, one of the videos ends a few seconds before the other one. I'm sure this is because of the different frame rates, but no combination of -framerate or -r, whether as an input or output parameter (or both), is giving me synced videos.  They start out in sync, but at the end there is a few seconds difference.

I have tried a number of things, as indicated above.  Here are some tests (don't mind the actual values; mostly these were just trying to see what the effect was):

ffmpeg -i %1 -r %outrate% -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryfast -y %output%

ffmpeg -i %1 -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryfast -y %output%

ffmpeg -r %inrate% -i %1 -r %outrate% -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryfast -shortest -y %output%

Here is the information for each file:

```
ffmpeg version N-91330-ga990184007 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 20.103 / 58. 20.103
  libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000020412f7a040] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1000
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000020412f7a040] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1000.
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '60fps.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2015-01-01T00:04:15.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:40.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31673 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 29717 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-01-01T00:04:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : iCatch Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : iCatch AVCC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-01-01T00:04:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : iCat Alias Data Handler
[avi @ 0000020413a3e280] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.1 : mono
Input #1, avi, from '29fps.avi':
  Duration: 00:05:04.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7266 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 7071 kb/s, 29.85 fps, 29.85 tbr, 29.85 tbn, 29.85 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

I know this is simple. But I can't come up with it, and my days of searching hasn't come up with it.  My Kung Fu is inferior.  I bow to you.

Comment: The async is not due to the base framerate. Sounds like the 2nd camera did variable frame-rate (is it a webcam/phone-camera?). Share the log of `ffmpeg -i 60fps.mp4 -i 29fps.mp4 2> logfile.txt`

Comment: @gyan: Edited the log information into the question.